# Angular matched route does not display

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a page running within an iFrame.
HTML snippet:

```
<div ng-app='APallet'>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
var aPalletServices = angular.module('APallet',['ngRoute']);
function palletRouteConfig($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    controller: PalletListCtrl,
    templateUrl: '/closeAndUplift_palletList.html'
})
.when('/add', {
    controller: PalletEditCtrl,
    templateUrl: '/closeAndUplift_palletEdit.html'
})
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}
aPalletServices.config(palletRouteConfig);

function PalletListCtrl($scope, $location){
$scope.addPallet = function(){
    $location.path('/add');
};
}
function PalletEditCtrl($scope, $location, $routeParams){
}
```

On start the closeAndUplift_palletList.html page displays correctly within ng-view. It has an add pallet button. When addPallet() is called through the PalletListCtrl the closeAndUplift_palletEdit.html page is retrieved from the server (as verified by the Chrome debugger) but it does not display in the ng-view. PalletEditCtrl also does not execute.

EDIT:
The problem seems to be that the page is in fact reloading after processing the request.

I feel that it has something to do with the fact that the page is loaded into an iframe. An additional factor may be that there is a token being passed in the URL.

I have tried using a  tag but it didn't help.

For the sake of completeness here is the "/" (closeAndUplift_palletList.html)

```
<a class="round button" ng-click="addPallet()" href="#">Add</a>
<table>
    <thead>
    <th>Pallet id</th>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat='pallet in pallets'>
        <td>{{pallet.palletId}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

`...
.when('/add', {
    controller: 'PalletEditCtrl', //this should be a string
    templateUrl: '/closeAndUplift_palletEdit.html'
})
...`

And declare controller as follows:

```
var Controllers = angular.module('Controllers', []);

Controllers.controller('PalletEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams'
  function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    //conlroller code here
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it didn't resolve the problem

Comment: Try changing this line var Controllers = angular.module('Controllers', []); to var Controllers = angular.module('APallet');